# How do I select the maximum date count and display

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, lambda

I have a Page where I need to display transactions that are Expired using the Max date in the database table as the criteria, 
For example: 
I have the following dates in my table with a Status of Expired in another Column

```
13/11/2020
19/05/2017
16/08/2003
```

I am selecting all items where the date is 13/11/2020 (max date) with Status of Expired and displaying the number of all records that match in a page.
Is there a way I can achieve this using orderbydescending or any other lambda or linq expression?

Comment: It probably is possible with EF, but I've found it easier to just write the `FromSqlRaw()` query.

Comment: Yes. It is possible. But, is it reasonable? Don't know! -- You have provided very little information about your application.What is your data source? What data do you have, how do you get it and in what form it is when you wish to analyze it. Are you using Entity Framework? All this must be consider.

Answer (score 0):

In the example `itemList` is a list of `Item`s that contain `ItemId` of type `int`, `ItemDate` of type `DateTime` and `ItemStatus` of type `string`.

This code takes **expired** item (`ItemStatus == "Expired"`) with **max date** for each **id** (`ItemId`) and places those elements to `maxDateForEachExpiredItem` list.

```
itemList.GroupBy(item => item.ItemId).ToList()
    .ForEach(itemGroup => maxDateForEachExpiredItem.Add(
        itemGroup.ToList()
            .Where(itemGroupElement => itemGroupElement.ItemStatus == "Expired")
            .OrderByDescending(itemGroupElement => itemGroupElement.ItemDate)
            .FirstOrDefault()));
```

In order to take number of such items where date is `"13/11/2020"`

```
maxDateForEachExpiredItem.Where(item => item.ItemDate == DateTime.Parse("11/13/2020")).Count()
```

Notice in `DateTime.Parse("11/13/2020")` the date format is *month/day/year*.

**Explanation:**

**1.** `itemList` is grouped by `ItemId`. Those groups of items are converted to list in order to iterate through them.

```
itemList.GroupBy(item => item.ItemId).ToList()
```

**2.** Iterate through each element (items grouped by `ItemId`) of list from part *1* and add something to list `maxDateForEachExpiredItem`.

```
.ForEach(itemGroup => maxDateForEachExpiredItem.Add(
```

**3.** Items grouped by `ItemId` are converted to list in order to iterate through the group.

```
itemGroup.ToList()
```

**4.** From group of items, grouped by `ItemId`, take items where `ItemStatus` is `Expired`.

```
.Where(itemGroupElement => itemGroupElement.ItemStatus == "Expired")
```

**5.** Order those items by `ItemDate`, starting from the newest date.

```
.OrderByDescending(itemGroupElement => itemGroupElement.ItemDate)
```

**6.** Finally, take the first item from such ordered list.

```
.FirstOrDefault()));
```

Here is entire example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item(1, "01/05/2015", "Expired"),
                new Item(1, "01/06/2015", "Expired"),
                new Item(1, "01/12/2020", "Active"),
                new Item(2, "01/03/2015", "Expired"),
                new Item(2, "01/07/2019", "Expired"),
                new Item(2, "01/10/2020", "Active"),
                new Item(2, "13/11/2020", "Expired"),
                new Item(3, "16/08/2003", "Expired"),
                new Item(3, "19/05/2017", "Expired"),
                new Item(3, "13/11/2020", "Expired"),
                new Item(3, "31/12/2020", "Active")
            };

            List<Item> maxDateForEachExpiredItem = new List<Item>();

            itemList.GroupBy(item => item.ItemId).ToList()
                .ForEach(itemGroup => maxDateForEachExpiredItem.Add(
                itemGroup.ToList()
                        .Where(itemGroupElement => itemGroupElement.ItemStatus == "Expired")
                        .OrderByDescending(itemGroupElement => itemGroupElement.ItemDate)
                        .FirstOrDefault()));

            Console.WriteLine("Max date for each expired item:\n");
            foreach (var item in maxDateForEachExpiredItem)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nNumber of items where date is 13/11/2020: " +
            $"{maxDateForEachExpiredItem.Where(item => item.ItemDate == DateTime.Parse("11/13/2020")).Count()}");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private class Item
        {
            public int ItemId { get; set; }
            public DateTime ItemDate { get; set; }
            public string ItemStatus { get; set; }

            public Item(int id, string date, string status)
            {
                ItemId = id;
                string[] dateParts = date.Split('/');
                ItemDate = new DateTime(int.Parse(dateParts[2]), int.Parse(dateParts[1]), int.Parse(dateParts[0]));
                ItemStatus = status;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"ItemId = {ItemId}, ItemDate = {ItemDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")}, ItemStatus = {ItemStatus}";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result

[image]

Comment: Wow... Over the top.There is no question you put a lot of effort into this answer, but we don't even know in what form the data is available. You've made assumptions about the data that might not exist. As far as the solution itself is concern -- I can barely follow this example. In additions to that, let us image to OP has 100.000+ rows of data to process? Does this scale well? No. -- There is is a simpler solution than this. One that doesn't require two `List` objects and doesn't do some really expensive operations on the collections.

Comment: OP wanted to select max date for expired items, as I understand, and then count such items based on the date. As there is need for single data (max date) in a group, there must be some inique data, here represented as `ItemId`. But I see your point, maybe solution could be simpler and less performance 'heavy'.  Is the solution itself hard to follow, or the entire example?

Comment: The OP states "I have a Page where I need to display transactions that are Expired..." That almost sounds like they have already queried the DB and filtered on "Expired"...maybe many not. Too many unknowns. -- "I am selecting all items where the date is 13/11/2020 (max date)" Does this mean they need the "max date" evaluated from the records or are the selecting a date value and what to use a variable date? Again, too many unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class Transactions
 {
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
 }
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Transactions> transactions = new List<Transactions>
        {
            new Transactions {Date = Convert.ToDateTime("13/11/2020") , Status="Expired"},
            new Transactions {Date = Convert.ToDateTime("19/05/2017") , Status="Expired"},
            new Transactions {Date = Convert.ToDateTime("16/08/2003") , Status="Expired"},
            new Transactions {Date = Convert.ToDateTime("13/11/2020") , Status="Expired"},
            new Transactions {Date = Convert.ToDateTime("13/11/2020") , Status="Expired"},
            new Transactions {Date = Convert.ToDateTime("13/11/2020") , Status="Active"},

        };

        var expiredStatusTransactions = transactions.Where(x => x.Status == "Expired")
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
        if(expiredStatusTransactions.Any())
        {
            var expiredTransactionDetails = expiredStatusTransactions.Where(x => x.Date == expiredStatusTransactions.FirstOrDefault().Date);
            if(expiredTransactionDetails.Any())
            {
                foreach(var details in expiredTransactionDetails)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Date : {details.Date.ToShortDateString()}     Status : {details.Status}");
                }

                Console.WriteLine($"Total Count : {expiredTransactionDetails.Count()}");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```